# Babylon.js disable frustum culling for SolidParticleSystem?

Tags: particle-system, babylonjs, culling

I'm attempting some simple data viz of a point cloud. My scene contains nothing but a 40K particle SolidParticleSystem and a small ground plane used for a visual reference when moving the camera. Every time world 0,0,0 goes out of the view frustum (by rotating or moving the camera), the *entire* SolidParticleSystem ceases to render.

It took me a long time to figure out why my particles kept disappearing for no apparent reason, until by trial and error of moving the camera around I figured out what was going on. The reference plane continues to render as expected.

Is it possible to defeat this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is:)
Just call mesh.alwaysSelectAsActiveMesh = true and this way the frustum test will be disabled